# nginx running script with root permissions

Tags: permissions, nginx

I wrote a small bash script that collects a crash report (some logs from `/var/log` and a couple of files from `/etc`) and the way I want this to work is through NGINX CGI.

Using a link, NGINX will trigger the script, collect all those files, and start a download once done.

My problem right now is with permissions. I can collect some parts of the files but not all of them (dmesg, syslog, etc.)

Comment: Can't you have the script run periodically (with cron) independently of nginx and let it collect/update the needed data in a location accessible to the web server. Having the webserver execute anything with root permissions sounds horribly insecure...

Comment: i agree and that has been bothering me, but having it running with cron won't work, say cron runs the job every 1 min and just after it runs it something nasty  happens and i grab the crash report it'll contain nothing useful about the issue that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your distribution, the logs in `/var/log` possibly have group read permission set for group `adm`.

You could add the user nginx is running as to the `adm` group to allow your CGI script to read those files. This way you do not need full root permissions for your script to read these logs.